# Array List Vs. Linked List

Tags: java

So I've been tasked an assignment to compare `LinkedLists` and `ArrayLists` for two different things.

part 1) 
randomly select locations inside the list and increment those values by 1 for each list type

part 2)
double each list size by adding random locations, and then immediately remove the same amount of random locations bring the list down to original size.

I feel I've accomplished this pretty well but my teacher is saying part 1 `ArrayList` should be faster (which it is in my code). He is saying `LinkedList` should be wayyy faster in part 2, which its the exact opposite for me... its way slower.. I've adding in `SYSO's` at different locations to verify that the lists are being modified correctly and everything and cant figure out why its not working out the way he says it should be.

can anyone spot what I've done wrong (if anything?). Thank you so much

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LinkedListVersusArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime, endTime, duration;
    List<Double> LL = new LinkedList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> AL = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int size = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Pick a list size (whole number only please)"));

    //fills the Linked List with random doubles
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        LL.add(Math.random());
    }
    //fills the ArrayList with random doubles
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        AL.add(Math.random());
    }

    //
    //Part 1
    //
    System.out.println("\nPART 1:\nBoth lists are now full of random numbers. \nI will now cycle through "
            + "and incremiment random locations " +size+ " times for each list.\n");

    //testing the LinkedList first for random access
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int x = (int)(LL.size()*Math.random());
        double y = LL.get(x);
        LL.set(x, y+1);
    }
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Linked List took: " +(duration/1000000) +" milli seconds");

    //testing the ArrayList now for random access
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int x = (int)(AL.size()*Math.random());
        double y = AL.get(x);
        AL.set(x, y+1);
    }
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Array List took: " +(duration/1000000) +" milli seconds");

    //
    //Part 2
    //
    System.out.println("\nPART 2:\nBoth lists will now get "+size+" slots added to them in random locations.\n"
            + "After this is complete, we will remove "+size+" slots from each list at random\n");

    //testing the LinkedList first for random adding/subtracting
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //add
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int x = (int)(LL.size()*Math.random());
        LL.add(x, 1.0);
    }
    //delete
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int x = (int)(LL.size()*Math.random());
        LL.remove(x);
    }
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Linked List took: " +(duration/1000000) +" milli seconds");

    //testing the ArrayList now for random adding/subtracting
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //add
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int x = (int)(AL.size()*Math.random());
        AL.add(x, 1.0);
    }
    //delete
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int x = (int)(AL.size()*Math.random());
        AL.remove(x);
    }
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Array List took: " +(duration/1000000) +" milli seconds");
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say "double each list size by adding random locations"?

Comment: adding elements. so if the arraylist has a size of 200 initially, after doubling it, it will have 400 elements. just by adding to random locations inside of the array

Comment: Doing micro benchmarks is non-trivial, especially on the JVM (because of the runtime's optimizing compiler). Theoretically, random adds on a linked list should be faster than on an ArrayList (Since the ArrayList will shift all elements right of the position), but the difference is not huge (since a linked list must scan through the list to find pos X) - especially for small lists.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I suspect the problem is that you are testing with numbers of items that are far too small to matter in your test results. Try adding 10 million items rather than 200. And repeat the test 10 times are running it once to warm up the JVM.

Comment: I've tested up to 50,000 so far. I'm running a test currently with 500,000 and it seems to be stuck on part 2.

Comment: Are your specs here word for word from what your professor gave you?

Comment: its not word for word but it conveys what he wanted us to do. I asked him in person in class to clarify

Comment: I want you to see the difference in performance between an array-base list (ArrayList) and a linked-list (List).

You are going to create a big list (use not-final SIZE for its size.  Ask the user at the start of the run) of Double, and fill it with random numbers..

Comment: For each data structure:

See how long it takes to random-access into the list. For SIZE times, pick a random location ((int)(Math.random()*SIZE))in the array, and increment it.  Do this twice, once with List,  and once with ArrayList. Find and use some system timer to determine how it takes for each data structure, and report the difference.  If it isn't a lot faster with ArrayList, you've done something wrong. One time for the combined add and remove set.

Comment: For each data structure:

Then, you are going to compare insertions and deletions.  After generating SIZE numbers in the data structure, you do SIZE random insertions (should be SIZE*2 big now), followed by SIZE random deletions (should go back to SIZE  ((int) (structure.size()*Math.random())).  Keep track of the times on this, 'cause the List oughta be a a freakin' lot faster.

Comment: these last 3 comments are what he posted for the assignment on our online curriculum - word for word direct copy/paste

Answer (score 3):

Apart from all the microbenchmarking issues which your code doesn't control for, your teacher's expectations for case 2 are also wrong. He is disregarding the cost of accessing a random element of `LinkedList` (the prerequisite to inserting at that spot) and overestimating the cost of inserting into the `ArrayList`. The cost of copying contiguous blocks of memory is much lower than the cost of chasing a long chain of pointers, which is what is required to access a random element of the `LinkedList`.

In reality `LinkedList` has a very narrow area of application where it is any improvement over `ArrayList`. For example, you could try to insert only near the front of the list. This way you'll emphasize the cost of moving elements in `ArrayList` and de-emphasize the cost of accessing a member of `LinkedList`.

Comment: do you mean by micro bench marking, the fact that I'm not accessing the same spots in order for each list for each test... i considered generating a random list of numbers (`size` long) and then using that for the iterations of the for loops. I thought that would be more "fair" but my teach said that shouldn't be necessary

Comment: I mean you don't warm up the code, you reuse the same JVM for all tests, you have all tests in line in the same method (precludes some optimizations), and many more. Microbenchmarking on a JIT-compiled, managed runtime is extremely deceptive.

Comment: thank you very much for the in dept response. I'm afraid at my level (1.5 classes into my programming career) this is a little over my head to say the least. I'm going to put some research into this and what you have said though. Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it